# GKTurnBasedParticipant information

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, game-center, gamekit

Is there any way of retrieving the player's name from a GKTurnBasedParticipant object? It appears that there is no way of displaying relevant information about the game player apart from an ugly playerID according to the class reference. Or am I missing something?

Thanks...

Answer (score 8):

Use `loadPlayersForIdentifiers:withCompletionHandler:` class method of GKPlayer. You pass an array of player ids as NSString and get an array of full GKPlayer objects.
Read [GKPlayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.